# Mongoose with mongodb how to return just saved object that have full or customize property with other collection?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need your help. I face with problem that I cant get full property or custom property that return from saved. My explain bellow :

**Post model :**

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    content: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: [true, "Post must be required"],
    },
    author: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
    liked: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
      },
    ],
    disliked: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
      },
    ],
    imageUrl: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

**User model :**

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        required: [true, 'Name must be required']
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        required: [true, 'Email must be required']
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        required: [true, 'Password must be required'],
        minlength: [6, 'Password must be at least 6 characters']
    },

}, {timestamps: true});
```

**function create new Post and response Post to client :**

```
exports.createOnePost = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("create one");
  try {
    const post = await Post.create({
      content: req.body.content,
      author: req.user.userId,
      liked: req.body.liked,
      imageUrl: req.body.imgUrl,
    });
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      data: { post },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

**After saved Post to database , I want to return full property of User and Post as well.**
**But I just received a Post :**

```
{
  content: 'sfdfsfd44434',
  author: new ObjectId("61c1e08837d77c6187b9a746"),
  liked: [],
  disliked: [],
  _id: new ObjectId("620c77d7574ce70b2417c1a1"),
  createdAt: 2022-02-16T04:04:39.016Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-02-16T04:04:39.016Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

**Hope that a solution from you guys. Thank you so much !**

Comment: use [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the user you can just return it in your response like this:

```js
res.status(200).json({
  status: "success",
  data: { post: { ...post.toObject(), author: req.user } },
});
```